# Can I reuse lightly used oil when I change an oil filter?

Tags: filter, engine, oil

I recently replaced the oil on my 4 stroke lawnmower engine, but - stupidly - I did not think to change the oil filter.    I've used the engine for maybe 2-4 hours subsequently.

I have now drained the oil out the engine (again), and it is a shiny brown color (I think darker then new, but it not dull and certainly not blackish.     Is it OK to reuse the oil I've drained, or is it really prudent to replace the oil with fresh oil again?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about Home Improvement.

Comment: When you drain the oil, does it tend to also drain the filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of an opinion based question rather than a "how do I do this" question.  Opinion based questions are discouraged here.  But I'm going to answer anyway and this is just my opinion.  The new oil got slightly contaminated by the old oil left in the filter. In the distant past it was a common practice to change the oil filter with every other oil change (cars and trucks) .  Some ppl did that, others replaced the filter every time. You should be fine re-using the drained oil with a new filter, but if you are really worried about, what is the cost of a the oil? It can't be too much for a lawn mower, so if it gives you peace of mind to get fresh oil and it only costs $10-$15, go for it.  That's pretty inexpensive to get peace of mind these days.